# Using degree symbol with lualatex and mathdesign package

Tags: luatex, fontspec, mathdesign

I started writing my thesis with pdflatex, since this is what the template used. But I have some large tables, which just barely do not fit. By reducing the font size they become a bit small, still taking up one page each, but wasting some space. I read that this can be avoided using [arbitrary font sizes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Arbitrary_sizes). For this reason I wanted to change to using lualatex. So here comes my actual issue: When I change to lualatex my ° symbols all turn into ř. I type them directly since they are easy to reach for me, I speak English and German and on the German keyboard layout its just easy to use it directly instead of \textdegree or \ang or whatever (and also nicer to edit).

So far I figured out that this is all related to using the mathdesign package. If I comment it my ° stay fine. However, this package seems to change the fonts for the whole document. It would be very nice to keep the same appearance as other theses from people before me. Probably not a strict requirement though. An important side question, since mathdesign changes the fonts, are those fonts still scalable, i.e. will I still be able to scale my tables?

So is there a way to allow me to use mathdesign with lualatex and type ° and also get it? Else I just have to change them all (there a many) to \ang or textdegree. However then I still need a similar font, see below.

Here are minimal examples. Using pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,pagesize,toc=bib,headings=normal,numbers=noendperiod,DIV=14,BCOR=5mm]{scrbook}

% does not seem to be  required for pdflatex anymore:
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}


% does not change ° into ř
% \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\textdegree}

\begin{document}
°             % degree symbol
\ang{20}
\char"00B0

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: with pdflatex]

° looks fine, but entering the unicode manually as \char"00B0 does not work and if I comment mathdesign it even disappears completely.

Using lualatex:

```
\RequirePackage{shellesc}              
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}            
\makeatletter                          
  \let\pdfshellescape\pdf@shellescape
\makeatother
\RequirePackage{luatex85}


\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,pagesize,toc=bib,headings=normal,numbers=noendperiod,DIV=14,BCOR=5mm]{scrbook}
% does not seem to be required for lualatex:
% \usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
°             % degree symbol
\ang{20}
\char"00B0

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: with lualatex]

Here, my typed ° also is changed to ř. Any help is appreciated. I just checked what fonts the pdfs of both variants use, its CharterBT-Roman in both cases. I guess this is not the scalable font that I want, will also look into if a similar font is availabe with lualatex ....

Comment: You probably should not rely on old style Type1 fonts when using unicode enabled engines.

Comment: I am using lualatex and I do not have issues with the ° symbol. Have you tried simply using completely fresh document without loading any packages? 'cause to me it seems that this is an issue with loaded packages and/or specified document settings

Comment: You can use also many scalable fonts with  `pdflatex`. E.g.: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookman}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10cm}{11cm}\selectfont A°
\end{document}` However, with any engine my recommendation is not use any other font size that `\small` or `\footnotesize` for big tables, and if this is not enough think about redesing the table. The reason is the consistency of font size across the document (i.e., it is not nice to see a different font size in each table).

Comment: @Fran, thx, I will try that. How do I know which fonts are scalable? I have many big tables of this size, so I would use the scaled font for all of those. Small tables can keep the default font.

Comment: @Raven, yes the problem only happens when I load the mathdesign package

Comment: With pdflatex arbitrary small fonts are possible too. But if you make the font so small or the table so large that nobody will ever be able or willing to read it, you could also simply remove the table.

Comment: unrelated to your question but you don't need `\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}            
\makeatletter                          
  \let\pdfshellescape\pdf@shellescape
\makeatother`  as you are using shellesc which makes the same availabe already as `\ShellEscapeStatus`  Also you are loading `luatex85` package, if you have ay packages that still require that compatibility layer then you should probably report that as a bug to the  package maintainer.

Comment: @user3917718 essentially all fonts used in tex these days are scalable you can check with pdffonts utility tyoe3 are generally) not scalable, type 1 are scalable.

Comment: You don’t give a MWE, but you seem to have a lot of obsolete packages cluttering up your preamble. One good thing about switching from 8-bit fonts to Unicode is that you can clear them out. The degree symbol works fine by default in LuaTeX, so some package must be breaking it. I would try commenting out any package whose purpose you’re not sure of, and re-enabling only the ones you need to fix an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\showsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}` is sufficient for me, I can stick with pdflatex. I needed a size in between footnotesize and scriptsize. I found [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21471) how to display the current sizes:

```
% ...preamble ..

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\fourteenpt{\fontsize{14}{15.5}\selectfont}
\newcommand*\totht[1]{\dimexpr\ht#1+\dp#1\relax}
\newcommand*\leading{{\setbox0\hbox{\strut}\the\totht0}}
\newcommand*\fntsize{{\setbox0\hbox{Mg}\the\totht0}}% total size of the letters Mg
\newcommand*\showsize[1]{{#1 {\ttfamily\string#1} (\f@size pt) \fntsize/\leading}\par}
\makeatother

% ...
% in the document
\showsize\tiny
\showsize\scriptsize
\showsize\footnotesize
\showsize\small
\showsize\normalsize
\showsize\large
\showsize\fourteenpt
\showsize\Large
\showsize\LARGE
\showsize\huge
\showsize\Huge
```

which gave me:
[image]

I then added a font size in between 8 and 10:

```
\newcommand{\myLargeTableFontSize}{\fontsize{9pt}{10.75pt}\selectfont}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define degree symbol with a command from gensymb package like:

```
\usepackage{gensymb}
% then just use \degree command instead of '°' symbol
\degree
```

If you want to find other symbols I highly recommend to check the website https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: The symbol is in the LaTeX kernel now. An old installation might need `\usepackage{textcomp}`.